# using pam_mount in WLAN setting

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, mount, pam, delayed-execution

I thought this should be a simple exercise here, but obviously I couldn't find a solution, yet. I use KDE on Ubuntu 12 LTS. I want to use libpam-mount to mount a nfs share to a directory within user's home, when logging into KDE-Desktop. (a little single sign on behaviour).

Actually I work with a laptop using a WLAN connection. The problem is, that WLAN connection is not established, yet, when logging in to KDE desktop (needs up to 10 seconds after logging in), so mounting network share by pam_mount doesn't work, too.

Is it possible to configure a delay for pam_mount? Does KDE itself offers any functionality for that scenario?

Regards ITL

Comment: No answers, yet? Did I miss an easy to find tutorial? :-/

Comment: The only way I could find to workaround this was to make my WLAN connection "available to all users". Of course, this isn't ideal - when you do this, it moves your password into /etc/ and of course, anyone else using the laptop with admin credentials could then see your password. Couldn't find a way to introduce a delay into libpam_mount though.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. For me the solution is okay. On KDE it is called "system connection".
@Scaine: You should formulate this as an answer.